# How to get a concatenated String of values from JSON response in Gatling?

Tags: json, scala, gatling

Hi I am getting back a response like this in Gatling Get call:

```
[
 {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
 {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
 {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

I want the firstnames to be concatenated in a comma seprated String. What is the best way to do that without parsing the JSon using any external libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using two features of Gatling:

1. JsonPath Check
2. transform

So the code would look like the following:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.firstName").ofType[String].findAll.transform(_.mkString(",")).saveAs("firstName")));
```